# Computation of Density for an Ideal Gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, density, partition-function

I'd like to get some help deriving the following result:
$$ \langle \rho(\mathbf{q}) \rangle = \frac{N}{V}$$
where
$$\rho(\mathbf{q}) = \sum_{i}^{N}\delta(\mathbf{q}_i-\mathbf{q}) $$
and $\mathbf{v} = v_x,v_y,v_z$, since we are working in a $6N$- dimensional phase space.
I tried doing this:
$$  \langle \rho(\mathbf{q}) \rangle = \frac{\int dq^{3N} dp^{3N}  e^{-\beta H}\rho(\mathbf{q})  }{Q} $$
Now, the partition function $Q_N$ can be factorized as
$$Q = Q_1 \cdot Q_2 \cdot...\cdot Q_N = \prod_{i}^{N} Q_i \tag{1}$$
and the Hamiltonian of the system can be rewritten as the sum of the Hamiltonians corresponding to each particle:
$$ \mathcal{H} = \sum_{i}^{N} H_i \tag{2}$$
Then I tried rewriting the sum as a one over the indices  $i \text{s.t. } i = j$ and over $i \ne j$:
$$ \langle \rho(\mathbf{q}) \rangle = \frac{\int d\mathbf{q}_i d\mathbf{p}_i  e^{-\beta \sum_{i = j}H_i }\delta(\mathbf{q-q}_i)  \cdot \int d\mathbf{q}_{i\ne j} d\mathbf{p}_{i \ne j}  e^{-\beta \sum_{i \ne j}H_i }\delta(\mathbf{q-q}_i)  }{\prod_i Q_i}$$
But couldn't get anything good out of this, unfortunately. I honestly don't see how to get an $N$ in the numerator. Also, the denominator is equal to $V$, therefore the integration along the momenta must not matter in the overall picture, but, again, I can't see how we should get rid of the integral in $d\mathbf{p}_i$ when the hamiltonians depend directly upon them. I'd be much more than glad if somebody could either help me see if I made any crucial mistakes along the way, or tell me how to go on performing these calculations.

Comment: I think you are making things much more complicated than needed. The integrals factor in $p$ and $q$ integrals, where the $p$ integrals in the numerator and denominator cancel (assuming $H_i$ does not depend on $q$)--perhaps it would help you to write down what $Q$ exactly is... Now the remaining position integrals give $NV^{N-1}/V^N=N/V$ (as long as $q\in V$). To see where the $NV^{N-1}$  comes from, start to write down the numerator for, say, $N=3$...it is not too hard. If I am not missing something, then all of this is correct and indeed straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's calculate the contribution of one of the terms in the sum:
$$\langle \rho \rangle_1=\frac{\int \Pi_idp_i dq_i \delta(q_1-q) e^{-\beta H_1 -\beta H_2 -...}}{Q_1^N}$$
where $H_j\equiv H(p_j,q_j)$ and $Q_1=\int dp_1 dq_1 e^{-\beta H_1}$. We find
$$\langle \rho \rangle_1=\frac{\int dp_1 e^{-\beta H_1(p_1,q)}\int \Pi_{i=2}dp_i dq_i  e^{-\beta H_2 -\beta H_3 -...}}{Q_1^{N}}$$
On the other hand in an ideal gas $Q_1= V \int dp_1 e^{-\beta H_1}$, because $H$ doesn't depend on $q$. Thus we have
$$\langle \rho \rangle_1=\frac{\frac{Q_1}{V}\times Q_1^{N-1}}{Q_1^{N}}=\frac{1}{V}$$
This is the contribution of $q_1$ in the sum. Considering all terms in the sum, we find
$$\langle \rho \rangle = N\times \frac{1}{V}= \frac{N}{V}$$